# DNS of site fails to resolve only on IE - 'This page can't be displayed'

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, internet-explorer

On IE (and only IE), our domain `coinchat.org` fails to resolve. IE displays the 'This page can't be displayed' error. In the IE console, the page is actually 'dnserror.htm' hinting that IE might have had issues resolving the domain.

This only happens on Internet Explorer, and has happened to many (if not all) of our IE users. We're completely confused as our DNS records should be correct. Ping on the same affected machines return the correct IP. Firefox/Chrome works fine on the same machines.

Dig response from a linux machine:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> coinchat.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52763
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;coinchat.org.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
coinchat.org.       69123   IN  A   66.228.48.212

;; Query time: 234 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 28 02:45:22 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```

What's more strange is that `kitty.coinchat.org`, a subdomain with the identical IP set, is accessible fine on IE.

What's actually happening?

Comment: IE is known to have DNS issues from time to time, mostly related to its security settings, proxy info or even windows firewall. 

Have you tried resetting IE to it's default settings? I found more details here: http://www.ehow.com/how_5325952_fix-internet-explorer-dns-error.html

Comment: We have gotten reports of this on 3 user PCs with completely different setups and I am able to reproduce it myself.

Comment: In order to find out what is happening you are going to need to capture the network traffic. That capture could be performed on the client machine or on the router to which it is connected. Or if the switch between the client and the router supports port mirroring, you could hook up a separate machine to perform a packet capture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more information is needed before it will be possible to answer. In particular a capture of the actual network traffic would help a lot in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a public facing site, verify you have an A Record for WWW and *

If you don't have these explicitly defined in your DNS server, IE will sometimes crap out.

Also, general IE troubleshooting dictates you should verify/clear the security/proxy settings, or set the browser back to defaults.

Comment: We have A records for WWW and *. Normal proxy/security settings, we've heard this from many users. Even browsershots displays this with IE https://i.imgr.com/ctg1BUQ.png but again, works fine with every other browser.

Comment: Try turning on/off Protected Mode; IE > Tools > Internet Options > Enable Protected Mode.  I've seen this happen with IE11 on some vendor portals as well; had to downgrade to IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure that you have a host header entry for each domain both with and without the www.

I experienced a similar issue, MSIE would return a 404 error when I entered just domain.com.  However, www.domain.com worked.  I have url rewrite rules that redirect non-www to www.domain.com.  But it seemed to only fail in MSIE.  Google Chrome worked fine.

Then I noticed that I had not entered a host header in IIS for the domain name sans www.  One I entered a host header entry in the IIS bindings, all browsers resolved the domain.com url.  I can't explain what some browsers worked.  I disabled cache during the testing.  But it works now.